Multiple named triggers on azure dev ops yaml pipeline
Is it possible to configure multiple triggers for a pipeline with different includes?
For context, we have 2 projects in one repository as we are developing one project as a replacement for the other:

If changes are made to projectA folder then we want to build projectA using a variable "projectPath"
If projectB has changes commited then we should build projectB.

Is it possible to add 2 triggers, both on the same branches, but one using include projectA and one including projectB? That way we can specify variables based on the triggering folder.
I have checked the docs but can't see any reference to this.

Hi @user2186028, have you checked the suggestions below? I am wondering to know if you have any question or need any other help.


we have 2 projects in one repository as we are developing one project as a replacement for the other

If by "replacement" you mean one of these projects and its correspondent pipeline will be removed in the future, I'd keep things simple and create 2 pipelines, each one with its own trigger.
If both projects use the same tasks to build the application, you can create a steps or job template such as /pipelines/jobs/build-application.yml and reference it in both pipelines, in order to reduce code duplication.
Or, as an alternative, use a different build template for each project.
Example:
Legacy pipeline (Project A)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - projectA/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Reference Project A specific variables
variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/project-a-variables.yaml

jobs:
- template: /pipelines/jobs/build-application.yml
  parameters:
    projectPath: $(projectPath) # from variable template
    # other parameters here

New pipeline (Project B)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - projectB/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Reference Project B specific variables
variables:
  - template: /pipelines/variables/project-b-variables.yaml

jobs:
- template: /pipelines/jobs/build-application.yml
  parameters:
    # set parameters here, if any

On the one hand, pipelines are very similar and it might seem unnecessary to have 2 pipelines doing almost the same thing.
But, on the other hand, each pipeline is much simpler and easier to understand. If the legacy project is removed in the future, you just need to remove the corresponding pipeline and templates, without making any changes to the new one.

By default, you may use the path filter: Paths
As a workaround, you may create one template to build your solution (Template usage reference, Template parameters) and then create two yamls with different path filter
# specific path build
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - project1

steps:
- template: steps/your_build.yml
  parameters:
    projectPath: Project1

or you may add the step
git diff --name-only --relative --diff-filter AMR HEAD~...HEAD .
check changed paths and set the needed value to your projectPath variable through the logging command: SetVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable

There is no out-of-the-box way to achieve your needs, because Azure DevOps does not have a predefined variable that can return the trigger path. Also, there isn't such info in REST API Builds - Get.
As a workaround, we can try the followings:

Get the latest version control change of the triggering repo from the variable Build.SourceVersion. See the details about this variable here.

Check the changes using REST API Commits - Get Changes

If the changes are from folder "projectB", then create an output variable projectPath and set its value to the path of your projectB. Otherwise, set its value to the path of projectA.


The complete yaml for your reference:
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - projectA/*
    - projectB/*

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $organization = "{your_organization}"
      $project = "{your_project}"
      $token = "{PAT}"
      
      # Base64 encode the PAT
      $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$token"))
      
      # Call the REST API to get the changes in the commit
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=7.1" `
                                    -Method Get `
                                    -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
      
      # Initialize the projpath variable
      $projpath = "projectA/projectA.csproj"
      
      # Check if any changes are in the "projectB" folder
      foreach ($change in $response.changes) {
          if ($change.item.path -like "*/projectB/*") {
              $projpath = "projectB/projectB.csproj"
              break
          }
      } 
      # Set the output variable
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectPath]$projpath"

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(projectPath)'


